# Cannot get virtual host with port to work on Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I am trying to set up a test and a live site on localhost.
I have the following directories set up:
/var/www/html/test/
/var/www/html/live/

So, by going to https://192.168.10.2, I want it to refer to /var/www/html/live/. (Note, I haven't tried setting this up yet)

By going to http://192.168.10.2:1881, I want it to refer to /var/www/html/test/

Here is what I have:
In /etc/httpd/conf.d, I have a file called test.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:1881

<VirtualHost *:1881>
ServerName 192.168.10.2
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test

    <Directory "/var/www/html/test">
        Options MultiViews Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In httpd.conf, I have added the line (directly under Listen 80):

```
Listen 1881
```

If I go to https://192.168.10.2/, I get a test page I set up. If I go to http://192.168.10.2:1881/, I get "This site can't be reached - ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Please let me know if you need anymore configuration files.

EDIT:
I ran the commands as suggested by @DanGahan

```
# netstat -anp | grep 1881
tcp6       0      0 :::1881                 :::*                    LISTEN      37931/httpd
# telnet 192.168.10.2:1881
telnet: 192.168.10.2:1881: Name or service not known
192.168.10.2:1881: Host name lookup failure
```

EDIT 2

```
# telnet 192.168.10.2 1881
Trying 192.168.10.2...
Connected to 192.168.10.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
#
```

EDIT 3 - IP tables

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDI_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDI_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDO_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDO_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
IN_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
IN_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:memcache ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A httpd.conf config as simple as

```
Listen 80
Listen 1881

NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 192.168.10.2
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/live
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:1881
<VirtualHost *:1881>
ServerName 192.168.10.2
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test
</VirtualHost>
```

Should do the trick. Run a 'netstat -anp | grep 1881' to confirm your listening on the new port, if that looks good try a tcp connection to it to confirm connectivity 'telnet 192.168.10.2 1881' - if that fails check iptables

Comment: I added the results of those commands to my question. Since it failed, I'm not sure what you mean by check iptables.

Comment: Looks like it may have just bound port 1881 to your ipv6 address rather than the ipv4 address - can you run the telnet again but with a space between the IP and port rather than the colon, so 'telnet 192.168.10.2 1881' - that will confirm

Comment: If the above is correct, change the Listen 1881 to Listen 192.168.10.2:1881, that'll force it you use the ipv4 address

Comment: See my EDIT2 on the question

Comment: Okay cool, that confirmed the listener is bound to the ipv4 address as the telnet tcp test connection successfully formed. Is the browser you attempt to connect from on the same host or a seperate box? Trying to work out whether it could still be a host based firewall (iptables) blocking your access from the browser

Comment: Changing to Listen 192.168.10.2:1881 had no effect. The setup is this. I'm running a windows server that has 2 VMs running linux. The web servers are on the linux VMs. 192.168.10.2 is the ip of the linux apache server.

Comment: Can you dump your iptables rules so we can rule that out, something like 'sudo iptables -L'

Comment: Added that to the question under EDIT 3

Comment: Looks like you're running firewalld (CentOS 7 at a guess), I'm not too hot with the new way to configure that but I think this command may do the trick and permit access to port 1881 (through the IN_public_allow chain) 'sudo iptables -A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1881 -j ACCEPT' - there's definitly a more elegant approach but hopefully that will do the trick

Comment: I opened up the page 168.10.2:1881  when logged into the machine that's running the apache server.

Comment: Yes!! That command worked. I can now access on the windows server as I needed. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad that sorted it. Just checked and apparently the firewalld approach to add the same rule and permanly save the config is 'firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=1881/tcp --permanent'